# Should questions phrased as declarations end with a question mark?

Tags: punctuation, questions

Should a question masquerading as a declaration—like, "I wonder if you have any suggestions?"—end with a question mark or a period?

Comment: see this:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/should-sentences-like-i-wonder-end-with-a-question-mark

Comment: While not a duplicate question, the selected answer is applicable and implies the answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/138488/17956

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer, originally, is that no question mark should be used and that instead, a full stop should. Since the main idea is that "I wonder", which is just a normal 'stating' clause and not a questioning one, and also since you are technically not expecting an answer, a question mark should be absolutely unnecessary. However, the contemporary usage of this phrase - "I wonder" - along with other phrases such as "because... (I can)?" or "surely, none of you can dare to disagree?", has been that of a question, and so placing a question mark at the end would still be acceptable. For the same reason, by the way, people do not usually place a comma after "surely" in sentences such as the one given in the example above, considering it to be the questioning clause, i.e. thinking it to be equivalent in meaning "isn't it evident that".

Comment: Since both can be correct, would it be correct to assume that the usage of the question mark indicates the _intonation_? I.e. the upward inflexion at the end of the question?

Comment: @Flater Definitely. All punctuation marks represent, in one way or another, a change in speech - or, instead, a particular change in speech is the representation of punctuation in speech; a question is, in most languages, represented by a particular change in intonation, as are other types of punctuation (e.g., exclamation marks). In English, questions are most commonly represented by a 2-3-1 or 2-3-2 intonation change (1=low; 3=high)